# How do I adjust the 'Create New Account' settings?

Tags: users, 6

New registrations are asked to create a password which is, in my opinion, excessively strong. Where do I go to adjust the password strength and other 'new account' settings?  When I looked in the listed modules, the 'User Module' was greyed out.

I am using Drupal version 6.

Comment: In case you did not know: You shouldn't be using Drupal 6 anymore **[On February 24th 2016, Drupal 6 will reach end of life and no longer be supported.](https://www.drupal.org/drupal-6-eol)**

Answer (score 0):

There were a few options for Drupal 6 so it's hard to give generic instructions. Check the module page for modules that include the word password and check for a "Configure" link.

*Take Note: Drupal 6 is no longer officially supported by the community. While there are some places that are offering long term support for Drupal 6, you should plan to move to Drupal 7 or 8 soon.*